# Reading from Excel iteratively from same excel file but on different sheets

Tags: excel, cplex

I am looking to solve a problem for different iteration and I need to read for each iteration data from a sheet in the same Excel file, like I want to solve my model for let's say for 4 times/iteration with at each time different data read from Excel on 4 different sheets / iteration. Is there any tricky code that I can implement on my main blog, to add this data first and solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 tabs for 3 options for number of kids:

[image]

Then in order to do a loop for those 3 options:

You first write

zooexcelmultisheet.mod

```
string paramsread=...;

tuple param
{
int nbKids;
}

{param} params=...;

assert card(params)==1;

int nbKids=first(params).nbKids;

// a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
tuple bus
{
key int nbSeats;
float cost;
}

// This is a tuple set
{bus} buses=...;

// asserts help make sure data is fine
assert forall(b in buses) b.nbSeats>0;
assert forall(b in buses) b.cost>0;

// decision variable array
dvar int+ nbBus[buses];

// objective
minimize 
 sum(b in buses) b.cost*nbBus[b];

// constraints 
subject to
{
 sum(b in buses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
}

tuple result
{
   key int nbSeats;
   int nbBuses;
}

{result} results={<b.nbSeats,nbBus[b]> | b in buses};

execute
{
writeln(results);
writeln("cost = ",cplex.getObjValue());
}
```

and then zooexcelmultisheet.dat

```
SheetConnection s("zoomultisheet.xlsx");

//paramsread="params1!A2";
params from SheetRead(s,paramsread);
buses from SheetRead(s,"buses!A2:B3");*
```

and then what you will run do do the loop for all 3 options:

```
{string} sheets={"params1","params2","params3"};


main { 
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("zooexcelmultisheet.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
  var data = new IloOplDataSource("zooexcelmultisheet.dat");

  for(var sheet in thisOplModel.sheets)
  {
  var data0=new IloOplDataElements();
  data0.paramsread=sheet+"!A2"; 
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
  opl.addDataSource(data0);
  opl.addDataSource(data);
  opl.generate();
  if (cplex.solve()) {

     opl.postProcess();
  } else {
     writeln("No solution");
  }


  opl.end();
}  
  data.end(); 
  def.end(); 
  cplex.end(); 
  source.end(); 
}
```

and you will get

```
{<40 6> <30 2>}
cost = 3800
 {<40 7> <30 1>}
cost = 3900
 {<40 8> <30 0>}
cost = 4000
```

Comment: First thanks a lot for your precious help ! it is really appreciated!

I have a more advanced question : for example, in the second iteration for the same range, the size of the array (range) will be bigger or smaller than the first iteration, how can i order to cplex to take the information from that part , an anticipated thanks!

Regards

Comment: Also did you set  paramsread  on excel ?  because i tried to introduce your aproach to my model and get the error Exception IBM ILOG Concert : Excel range is unknown.